# CheckBoxTreeItems always independent, not rendered properly. Why?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX and I am trying to create a simple TreeTableView, containing a
single Boolean column and is rendered with a CheckBoxTreeTableCell.

The problem I am having is that the two CheckBoxTreeItems seem independent (selecting
the root doesn't select the child and the other way around). I even try setting the
independancy manually (see commented code) but it makes no difference.

The documentation for CheckBoxTreeItems says that "By default, CheckBoxTreeItem instances are dependent", which doesn't seem to work for me.

Also, I am expecting toString() value of the Model class to be shown as checkboxes'
texts but no text is drawn, only empty checkboxes. Why is this?

And finally, it is possible to set a graphic node for a CheckBoxTreeItem, and this
node is then shown to the left of the CheckBoxTreeItem. Would it be possible to have
it drawn between the checkbox and the checkbox text instead? Something like:

[x][graphic_node]A simple checkbox text

I am using JDK 1.8.0_40

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class CheckBoxTreeItemTest extends Application {

private Stage stage;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public final void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    this.stage = stage;

    final CheckBoxTreeItem<Model> root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new Model("Root"));
    final CheckBoxTreeItem<Model> parent = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new Model("Parent"));
    final CheckBoxTreeItem<Model> child = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new Model("Child"));

    //Manually setting independence makes no difference 
    /*parent.setIndependent(false);
    child.setIndependent(false);
    root.setIndependent(false);*/

    parent.getChildren().add(child);
    root.getChildren().add(parent);

    final TreeTableColumn<Model, Boolean> selectedColumn = 
            new TreeTableColumn<>("Selection");

    selectedColumn.setEditable(true);
    selectedColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().getValue().selectedProperty());
    selectedColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeTableCell.<Model>forTreeTableColumn(selectedColumn));

    final TreeTableView<Model> table = new TreeTableView<>(root);
    table.setShowRoot(false);
    table.setEditable(true);    
    table.getColumns().add(selectedColumn);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(table, 500, 350);     
    stage.setScene(scene);             
    stage.show();
}

private class Model {
    private final BooleanProperty selected;
    private final StringProperty name;

    public Model(final String name) {
        this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public final void setSelected(final boolean selected) {
        this.selected.set(selected);    
    }

    public final boolean isSelected() { 
        return selected.get();
    }

    public final BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {       
        return selected;
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model [selected=" + selected + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CheckBoxTreeItem` provides a [`selected` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBoxTreeItem.html#selectedProperty). It is this property that respects the `independent` state of the `CheckBoxTreeItem` (i.e. if the parent `CheckBoxTreeItem` is selected, then this `CheckBoxTreeItem` is automatically selected, etc).

However, in your application, the `CheckBoxTreeItem`'s `selected` property is not the property represented by the item, because you set the cell value factory to map to the `selected` property of the `Model` instance represented by the item. So checking the check box sets `Model.selected` to `true`, but of course there is no logic managing that property in terms of parent and/or child selected properties.

Typically when you have your own boolean property representing the state of the checkbox, you would not use a `CheckBoxTreeItem`. However, if you want the functionality of the non-independent properties, you would have to implement that yourself. Since that logic is actually quite complicated, if you want your own `Model` class, I would just bidirectionally bind the property of interest to the `CheckBoxTreeItem`'s `selectedProperty`:

```
    Model rootModel = new Model("Root");
    final CheckBoxTreeItem<Model> root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(rootModel);
    root.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(rootModel.selectedProperty());

    Model parentModel = new Model("Parent");
    final CheckBoxTreeItem<Model> parent = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>( parentModel);
    parent.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(parentModel.selectedProperty());

    Model childModel = new Model("Child");
    final CheckBoxTreeItem<Model> child = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(childModel);
    child.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(childModel.selectedProperty());
```

Comment: James_D, thank you very much, that is exactly what I wanted. My original solution was to have custom cell rendering with a checkbox and an image, but, as you say, I figured out that the logic for dependency between the checkboxes could be quite complex. That is why I was trying to get that for free by using CheckBoxTreeItem. This is a very elegant solution you provided and I will implement it in my code